# How to check the user role in the header php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'am new in PHP programming. I've try so many solution but it still not working.
Also confuse on how to check the user role based on the level.. Can somebody help me to solve this.

When I run this code,its appear "Notice: Undefined index: level in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTMb\admin\headerTESTLevel.php on line 122".

Here is my code.

```html
headerTESTLevel.php

<?php include 'config.php' ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Record Management System</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Charisma, a fully featured, responsive, HTML5, Bootstrap admin template.">
    <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Usman">

    <!-- The styles -->
    <link id="bs-css" href="css/bootstrap-cerulean.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="css/charisma-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'>
    <link href='bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/colorbox/example3/colorbox.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/responsive-tables/responsive-tables.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='bower_components/bootstrap-tour/build/css/bootstrap-tour.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/jquery.noty.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/noty_theme_default.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/elfinder.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/elfinder.theme.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/jquery.iphone.toggle.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/uploadify.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='css/animate.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- The HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- The fav icon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

</head>

<body>
<?php require ('include/database.php'); ?>
<?php require ('session.php'); ?>
<?php if (!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) { ?>
    <!-- topbar starts -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left animated flip">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php"> <img alt="Charisma Logo" src="img/logo20.png" class="hidden-xs"/>
                <span>ICT MS</span></a>

            <!-- user dropdown starts -->
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
<?php
 include('include/database.php');
 $user_query=mysql_query("select *  from user where user_id='$id_session'")or die(mysql_error());
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query); {
?>
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"> <?php echo $row['nama']; ?></span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>


                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <!---<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>-->
                    <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>        <!-- user dropdown ends -->

            
            <div class="btn-group pull-right theme-container animated tada">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></i><span
                        class="hidden-sm hidden-xs"> Change Theme / Skin</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="themes">
                    <li><a data-value="classic" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Classic</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="cerulean" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Cerulean</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="cyborg" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Cyborg</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="simplex" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Simplex</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="darkly" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Darkly</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="lumen" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Lumen</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="slate" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Slate</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="spacelab" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> Spacelab</a></li>
                    <li><a data-value="united" href="#"><i class="whitespace"></i> United</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- topbar ends -->
<?php } ?>
<div class="ch-container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php if (!isset($no_visible_elements) || !$no_visible_elements) { ?>

        <!-- left menu starts -->
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="sidebar-nav">
                <div class="nav-canvas">
                    <div class="nav-sm nav nav-stacked">

                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked main-menu">
     
      <?php
       include "include/database.php";
     
       if($_SESSION['level'] == 'admin')
       {
          echo' <li class="nav-header">Main</li>
        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span> Home</span></a></li>
        
        <li class="accordion">
         <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span>Staff</span></a>
         <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a class="ajax-link" href="item.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Data Staf</span></a></li>
          <li><a class="ajax-link" href="addStaf.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> + Staf Baru</span></a></li>
          <li><a class="ajax-link" href="user.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><span> Admin Account</span></a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="accordion">
         <a href="unit.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> Unit</span></a>
          
        </li>
        <li class="accordion">
         <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> Jawatan</span></a>
         
        </li>
        <li class="accordion">
         <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span> Contact</span></a>
         
        </li>
        <li class="accordion">
         <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i><span>Senarai Kenderaan</span></a>
         
        </li>
       ';} 
      ?>
                 
     
     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <!-- left menu ends -->

  <!--      <noscript>
            <div class="alert alert-block col-md-12">
                <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>

                <p>You need to have <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript" target="_blank">JavaScript</a>
                    enabled to use this site.</p>
            </div>
        </noscript>-->

        <div id="content" class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10">
            <!-- content starts -->
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['level']` is not defined in your code. Where is it defined?

Comment: thank you, its working..

Comment: So, how did you solve it?

Comment: its working to one user only, another level its still not working. How to declare for another user ??

Comment: Is it the same error?

Comment: no, if i login as another role user.header will read the header as admin too. so, whether i log in as different role, it will display the same header.

Comment: Then you have to find a way to set `$_SESSION['level']` according to the user. Or you have to make a different post.